# Pretty-print newlines but not extra newlines

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a way, using the pretty printing machinery, to say, there needs to be a newline here, but not more than one?

I have added an S-expression node type for comments, and I am trying to make the pretty printer output them successfully. This is an example input in the preferred format

```
(defun f ()
  ; a
  ; b
  z)
```

This is one attempt at pretty printing

```
(set-pprint-dispatch `(cons (eql ,+comment+)) #'print-comment)
```

and then

```
(defun print-comment (*standard-output* a)
  (princ (cadr a)))
```

Produces this incorrect output

```
(DEFUN F () ; a ; b Z)
```

So the pretty printer doesn't know comments need to go on separate lines, fair enough, I need to tell it that

```
(defun print-comment (*standard-output* a)
  (pprint-newline :mandatory)
  (princ (cadr a))
  (pprint-newline :mandatory))
```

And get this output

```
(DEFUN F ()

  ; a


  ; b

  Z)
```

Which is no good either. Is there a way to tell the pretty printer to output a newline without the extra newlines?

Comment: Can you not use format with the `~&` directive  instead of princ and the mandatory newlines ? (`~&` doesn't print a newline if there is already one, on the contrary of `~%`).

Comment: @Ehvince I tried that just now, but it still prints the extra blank lines just the same.

Comment: What if you do `fresh-line` instead of `pprint-newline`? Also I don’t think you actually want a mandatory newline in any sense before the comment. What about `(defun print-comment (s a) (pprint-logical-block (s a :per-line-prefix "; ") (princ (second a) s)))` ?

Comment: @DanRobertson `fresh-line` still prints the extra blank lines.

Comment: @DanRobertson but `per-line-prefix` seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @DanRobertson ... or not. Turns out it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't, depending on apparently unrelated code in the outer loop in a way that I cannot exactly characterize. Also produces different output in SBCL versus CCL, which doesn't surprise me, no way two teams could implement a spec that complex and get identical results in all cases.